# Changed from Hub to Pivot (ItemsWrapGrid not working)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App (WinRT)**

I used the **inbuilt Hub template**. I replaced this **Hub** by **pivot**. But the items present inside the gridview are not wrapping and going out of boundary. What could be missing?

**Old code:**

```
 <Hub x:Name="Hub" 
             x:Uid="Hub"   
             Background="{ThemeResource HubBackgroundImageBrush}">
            <Hub.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="KeyTreat"
                       Style="{StaticResource CategoriesText}"
                        FontSize="48"
                        Margin="0,20,0,0">

                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Hub.HeaderTemplate>

            <HubSection x:Uid="HubSectionCategories" 
                        Header="CATEGORIES" 
                        Width="Auto"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                         DataContext="{Binding Groups[0]}" 
                        HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <GridView
                        Margin="0,9.5,0,0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                        AutomationProperties.Name="Categories in Key Treat"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StandardCategoriesItemTemplate}"
                        SelectionMode="None"
                        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
                        ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <ItemsWrapGrid />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    </GridView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>

        </Hub>
```

**New Code:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <Pivot 
            x:Uid="Pivot" 
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            Title="MY APPLICATION" 
            x:Name="pivot"
            CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <PivotItem
                x:Uid="PivotItem1"
                Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
                Header="first"
                   Width="Auto"                       
                 DataContext="{Binding Groups[0]}" 

                CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True"
                >
                    <GridView
                        Margin="0,9.5,0,0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                        AutomationProperties.Name="Categories in Key Treat"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StandardCategoriesItemTemplate}"
                        SelectionMode="None"
                        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
                        ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </GridView>
            </PivotItem>

        </Pivot>
   </Grid>
```

Problem is that    is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: If this is an answer then perhaps you could provide some detail as to how this solved your issue for future visitors.